# How to call 2 different stored procedures from java in oracle?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a scenario where I want to call 2 different stored procedures using different threads.
These procedures take some time in processing so it would be better if both are running at the same time.
I tried this using 2 threads but there is something wrong, first call returns without any processing and no errors.
Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: Yes, witch technologies are you using? direct jdbc, framework as hibernate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a connection in each thread to achieve this.  To call each oracle procedure in a separated connection.

Comment: I had thought of this, but this option is not feasible for me.Thanks anyway.